# Check if thread is a boost thread

Tags: c++, boost, pthreads

For purposes of thread local cleanup I need to create an assertion that checks if the current thread was created via boost::thread.  How can I can check if this was the case? That is, how can I check if the current thread is handled by boost::thread?

I simply need this to do a cleanup of thread local storage when the thread exits. Boost's thread_local_ptr appears to only work if the thread itself is a boost thread.

Note that I'm not doing the check at cleanup time, but sometime during the life of the thread. Some function calls one of our API/callbacks (indirectly) causing me to allocate thread-local storage. Only boost threads are allowed to do this, so I need to detect at that moment if the thread is not a boost thread.

---

Refer to [Destruction of static class members in Thread local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592033/destruction-of-static-class-members-in-thread-local-storage) for the problem of not having a generic cleanup handler. I answered that and realized pthread_clenaup_push won't actually work: it isn't called on a clean exit form the thread.

---

While I don't have answer to detect a boost thread the chosen answer does solve the root of my problem. Boost thread_specific_ptr's will call their cleanup in any pthread. It must have been something else causing it not to work for me, as an isolated test shows that it does work.

Comment: I don't think you really want a *static* assertion. Static assertions are checked at compile time, but that's too soon to check how something was created a run time. I think you just want an ordinary assertion.

Comment: I corrected the static assertion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The premise for your question is mistaken :) boost::thread_specific_ptr works even if the thread is not a boost thread. Think about it -- how would thread specific storage for the main thread work, seeing as it's impossible for it to be created by boost? I have used boost::thread_specific_ptr from the main thread fine, and although I haven't examined boost::thread_specific_ptr's implementation, the most obvious way of implementing it would work even for non-boost threads. Most operating systems let you get a unique ID number for the current thread, which you can then use as an index into a map/array/hashtable.

More likely you have a different bug that prevents the behavior you're expecting to see from happening. You should open a separate question with a small compilable code sample illustrating the unexpected behavior.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how it works though. What pthread function makes this work?  I'm running tests to see if it is actually the case.

Comment: Got it, the call to pthread_key_create accepts a destructor. So this is good enough for me, though what if the thread is not created via pthreads? ;)

Comment: I was actually thinking of pthread_self(), which gives you a unique integer for the current thread. The pthread_key* functions may be more efficient though; I remember in the ELF ABI for Linux that they specifically support thread local storage, which makes me think there must be direct CPU support for it in the form of special registers, and pthread_key_* may take advantage of those. As far as if it's not created via pthreads -- you kid, but if there are multiple thread implementations available on an OS, chances are they all reduce down to the same core, so things will likely work.

Comment: Any hint on how this is implemented on windows?

Comment: Quoting from http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/thread_local_storage.html : "on some platforms, cleanup of thread-specific data is not performed for threads created with the platform's native API."

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with a static assertion: That would mean you could detect it at compile time, and that's impossible.

Assuming you mean a runtime check though:

If you don't mix `boost::thread` with other methods, then the problem just goes away. Any libraries that are creating threads should already be dealing with their own threads automatically (or per a shutdown function the API documents that you must call).

Otherwise you can keep, for example, a container of all `pthread_t`s you create not using `boost::thread` and check if the thread is in the container when shutting down. If it's not in the container then it was created using `boost::thread`.

EDIT: Instead of trying to detect if it was created with `boost::thread`, have you considered setting up your application so that the API callback can only occur in threads created with `boost::thread`? This way you prevent the problem up front and eliminate the need for a check that, if it even exists, would be painful to implement.

Comment: Sorry, yes, a runtime assertion. The issue is with callbacks to our code from 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Each time a boost thread ends, all the [Thread Specific Data](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/thread/thread_local_storage.html) gets cleaned. TSD is a pointer, calling `delete p*` at destruction/reset.

Optionally, instead of `delete p*`, a cleanup handler can get called for each item. That handler is specified on the TLS constructor, and you can use the cleanup function to do the one time cleaning.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/tss.hpp>

void cleanup(int* _ignored) {
    std::cout << "TLS cleanup" << std::endl;
}

void thread_func() {
    boost::thread_specific_ptr<int> x(cleanup);
    x.reset((int*)1); // Force cleanup to be called on this thread

    std::cout << "Thread begin" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    boost::thread::thread t(thread_func);

    t.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question is, does this actually guarantee the cleanup of data if the thread is not a boost::thread?