# How to release the object in a TLS-slot at thread exit on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, thread-local-storage

for example, in a multi-thread program:

```
struct TLSObject;

void foo()
{
    TLSObject* p = TlsGetValue(slot);
    if (p == 0) {
        p = new TLSObject;
        TlsSetValue(slot, p);
    }
    // doing something with p
}
```

the first time to call foo() in any thread will makes a new TLSObject.

my question is:
How to delete a TLSObject(if I don't use boost::thread and boost::thread_specific_ptr) ?

boost::thread_specific_ptr can do cleanup work at thread exit,
but it depends on boost::thread I guess, not for normal OS thread,
and it's slow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright. For Windows Vista and above, as James McNellis said - we
could use [FlsCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682664%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

For a DLL, we could just use DllMain, if reason parameter equals
to DLL_THREAD_DETACH, we do the cleanup. An alternative might be
to use _pRawDllMain, it's just like another DllMain, you could
find it from [boost source](https://github.com/boostorg/thread/blob/master/src/win32/tss_pe.cpp).

For an EXE, we could use TLS callback, please have a look at
[here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8113/Thread-Local-Storage-The-C-Way) and [here](http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=183), and, of course, [boost source](https://github.com/boostorg/thread/blob/master/src/win32/tss_pe.cpp). In
practice, it works on Windows XP, but I found that optimizations
may make it ineffective, so be careful with optimizations, or make
a explicit reference to the pointer of your callback function.

Save the code below to tls.cpp and add it to your project, no
matter it's exe or dll, it will work. Note that for a DLL on
Windows Vista and above the onThreadExit function may be called
twice - one from dll_callback and one from tls_callback.

```
#include <windows.h>

extern void onThreadExit();

static void NTAPI tls_callback(PVOID, DWORD reason, PVOID)
{
    if (reason == DLL_THREAD_DETACH) {
        onThreadExit();
    }
}

static BOOL WINAPI dll_callback(LPVOID, DWORD reason, LPVOID)
{
    if (reason == DLL_THREAD_DETACH) {
        onThreadExit();
    }
    return TRUE;
}

#pragma section(".CRT$XLY",long,read)
extern "C" __declspec(allocate(".CRT$XLY")) PIMAGE_TLS_CALLBACK _xl_y = tls_callback;

extern "C"
{
    extern BOOL (WINAPI * const _pRawDllMain)(HANDLE, DWORD, LPVOID) = &dll_callback;
}

#pragma comment(linker, "/INCLUDE:__tls_used")
#pragma comment(linker, "/INCLUDE:__xl_y")
```

If you think it's obscure, use boost's [at_thread_exit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.this_thread.atthreadexit), the
complexity is hidden. In fact the code above is a simplified
version of boost tls. And if you do not want to use boost, on
Windows system this is a alternative.

Or, a more generic way: [thread_local](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/thread_local).

Comment: Very inventive, but a word of caution: this approach is flaky and might break in the future silently (as in no tls_callback will be invoked), it also does not guarantee that there will be no other CRT code invoked after the callback, which depending on what you're doing can potentially allocate TLS again.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `TlsAlloc`, use [`FlsAlloc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682664.aspx) (and related `Fls*` functions).  With FLS, you register a cleanup callback which the OS will call on the thread before the thread terminates, giving you the opportunity to clean up.

Comment: James, I know you are a VC Engineer, do the standard library and VC compiler use the Fls or Tls? Is it always safe to use Fls in place of Tls (is it actually recommended)? I know Fls is quite limited in terms of slots compared to Tls.

Comment: Recent versions of the runtime libraries use FLS on all operating systems where they are available (FLS was introduced in Windows Vista).  There are 128 FLS slots available to the process (FLS_MAXIMUM_AVAILABLE).

Comment: As you said, FLS was introduced in Windows Vista, what about Windows XP ? Can I have other alternative ?

Comment: @amanjiang No. Windows XP is dead. I do not know of any solution that works on Windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

A 'boost::thread_specific_ptr' should work on any thread (according to the answer to my question: [Check if thread is a boost thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786521/check-if-thread-is-a-boost-thread))

About it being slow, yes, it isn't ideal. However, what you can do is use whatever normal TLS mechanism you wish (I used the GCC specific modifier) and then create an additional thread_specific_ptr which cleans up the data (create a wrapper to your true TLS pointer). So creation and deletion of the TLS is a bit expensive, but access is unaffected.

Comment: I did a test just now, thread_specific_ptr could work with _beginthreadex, it's a good news. Now I use Win32 TLS for access and thread_specific_ptr for cleanup, it works ! This idea was awesome, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able use one of the many scope exit mechanisms to achieve this, for example [this one](https://code.google.com/p/scope-exit/).

Another alternative would be to wrap your TLSObject into an RAII class that releases the object when the RAII wrapper is destroyed. This is a very common resource management pattern and definitely applicable here.

Comment: Scope exit doesn't apply to thread lifetime. He wants to cleanup the object when the thread ends, not when a scope exits.