# Would the function pthread_cleanup_push() work with threads created with _beginthreadex()?

Tags: windows, multithreading, pthreads, thread-local

In my project I use a third-party DLL, that creates some threads, which in turn call my function. The threads in the third-party DLL are created with _beginthreadex(), the DLL is compiled with MSVC.
My project is compiled with MINGW.

In my function I use the thread-local variable, using the __thread keyword, like the following:

```
__thread Env* env;

Env* getEnv() {
   if(env) return env;
   return env = createNewEnv();
}

// called by the 3rd-party thread
void myFunction() {
   Env* env = getEnv();
   // do work
}
```

From time to time the third-party library kills all threads and later spawn new ones, for which I receive a notification. In order to prevent memory leak I need to delete the Env instances created by the now-dead threads. The problem is that I don't know how to access these instances, because the pointers are thread-local.

I've google up an idea to use the pthread_cleanup_push() function, which is present in the MINGW runtime. That would ideally solve my issue, but I'm not sure if it would work with threads created with _beginthreadex().

Any ideas? May be another workaround exists?

Comment: I'm guessing that the `pthread_cleanup_push()` technique only works with threads the pthreads library knows about, but you can always test that hypothesis by putting a `printf()` (or whatever) in the callback-function and seeing if it gets printed.

Comment: You are right. Moreover, it turned out that I misunderstood the usage of this function, it's not applicable in my case. Now considering the pthread_key_create() with destructor.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the idea of using `pthread_cleanup_push()` turned out completely wrong, because it can be used only within a thread main function, which I don't have access to. It is not even a  real function. Actually it's a `#defined` chunk of code, which should be used together with `pthread_cleanup_pop()`.

I solved the problem of cleaning thread-local variables by implementing a `dllmain()` in which I process the `DLL_THREAD_DETACH` event.

Very useful discussion on this topic is here:
[How to release the object in a TLS-slot at thread exit on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650956/how-to-release-the-object-in-a-tls-slot-at-thread-exit-on-windows)